# App Deployment: Django not installing on server- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Tags: web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a Django App and for some reason, I keep getting this error. It seems to me that Django is not installed but it also errors when installing. Thank you for the help on this. I am deploying on Amazon EC2

---

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip----:~/quotes$ pip install Django
Collecting Django
  Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ceP6se/Django/setup.py", line 32, in 
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in 
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in 
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ceP6se/Django/
```

Comment: I have figured this issue out. the problem was that I needed to downgrade my version of Django from 2.7 > 1.11 because I was using an older version of python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django has stopped its support for Python 2 version, still you can try installing 1.11 version by using the below code.

```
pip install Django==1.11
```

Comment: Even better would be to pin the version so that the latest 1.11 would be used, such as: ``django >=1.11,<2.0``

Comment: This is not a real answer and it's all around for these kinda error! OP needs a way to install django 2 not an older version

Answer (score 1):

According to the django 2.0 release notes, The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7 ([Check it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/))

So you can choose to use an older version of Django and then install it with this command:

```
pip install 'Django<2'
```

but if you decided to buildup your project using Django>=2.0 then you should create a virtual environment with python 3.4 or higher this way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv
mkdir ~/myproject
cd ~/myproject
virtualenv -p `which python3` myprojectenv
source ~/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/activate
python -V
```

it should output something like this:

```
Python 3.X.Y
```

Now you are able to install the latest version of Django without any error:

```
pip install Django
```

Good luck,

Comment: Yes, Thank for your response. I have previously solved this problem by stepping back to Django 1.11. After doing that it worked.