# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache' while installing Django 2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm using ubuntu and I got `python 2.7` and `python 3.4.3` installed on my OS.

I'm trying to upgrade to `Django 2`. ButI get this error while trying to install it using `pip install -U Django` or `pip install Django --upgrade`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 17, in
>      File "/tmp/pip_build_alex/Django/setup.py", line 32, in
>   
>   version = **import**('django').get_version()   File "django/**init**.py", line 1, in 
>   from django.utils.version import get_version   File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in 
>   @functools.lru_cache() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache' Complete output from command python setup.py
>   egg_info: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 17, in
>
> File "/tmp/pip_build_alex/Django/setup.py", line 32, in
>
> version = **import**('django').get_version()
>
> File "django/**init**.py", line 1, in
>
> from django.utils.version import get_version
>
> File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in
>
> @functools.lru_cache()
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196124/there-are-errors-when-i-install-django-by-git) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660508/app-deployment-django-not-installing-on-server-attributeerror-module-object), only to see that answers are offering OP to install a lower version of django!, but that's not a real answer to such question.

I tried `alias python=python3` to set python 3 as default python but failed to get a working solution.

How can I install Django 2 in a OS with 2 versions of python without getting this error?

Comment: did you try `pip3 install Django --upgrade` ?

Comment: you should be using a virtualenv, and not installing packages to system python.  Check out https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/

Comment: because if you do aliasing and other stuff with different python versions, you are going to seriously screw up your entire operating system.

Comment: @Jason I didn't permanently did that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing Django: Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rcF9a5/Django/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684498/trouble-installing-django-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing django using pip3. But since I didn't have pip3 package installed on my OS, first I had to install it using:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Then I successfully installed Django 2.0 using:

```
pip3 install Django --upgrade
```